# Comparing list in python

Tags: python, list, compare

Hey im starting to learn python and after a loop function i got a list which looks like this

```
>>>print test

['a','b','c','d']
['a','c','d','e']
['b','d','e','f']
```

I want to compare it and found things like intersection BUT as the two lists are under one name i can't get it done.

I want to compare the lists and count the letters. Expectation:

```
d, 3
a, 2
b, 2
```

etc

Someone can help me with that?

best regards

Comment: No Python list prints like that given what you've shown. Assuming what you actually have is a list of lists, just loop over each list in turn to count things (`for sublist in test: for item in sublist: do stuff`). There are endless questions here on StackOverflow that deal with counting occurrences of a character.

Comment: What do you want to compare to what? Your goal seems to be counting the global occurrences of each letter ... for this, use `list.count`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have list of lists, then you can use `collections.Counter` to count letters:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> test = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','c','d','e'],['b','d','e','f']]
>>> Counter(i for x in test for i in x)
Counter({'d': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'e': 2, 'f': 1})
```

or, as inspectorG4dget suggested in comments, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> test = ['test','test2']
>>> Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(test))
Counter({'t': 4, 's': 2, 'e': 2, '2': 1})
```

Comment: Okay thanks i understand it works fine. But what to do if you have instead of letters words? F.e. : ['test','test2']

Comment: `itertools.chain.from_iterable` - you won't have to manually flatten the list

Comment: Thank you. And if i want to count the words? So the output would be: 'test':1 'test2':1

Comment: @user1477042 Counter(test)